# In-house Apple Watch app development and deployment?

Tags: ios, deployment, watchkit, apple-watch

We currently develop a lot of in house iOS apps.  We deploy them using a homegrown AppStore and iOS over-the-air install support.

That said, is it possible to deploy Apple Watch apps in the same manner?  Or are you restricted to Apple AppStore apps only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple Watch apps are bundled with iPhone apps. You can definitely deploy them in the same manner you deploy iOS apps because they are contained in the iOS app.